# How can I get Quicksilver to open bookmarked URLs in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, quicksilver

I'd like to be able to trigger QS and then start typing "gmail" or "weather" or the name of whatever bookmark I'd like to open, and have the previously bookmarked site open in Chrome, my default browser. Is it possible to do this with Chrome?

(I was able to do this with Quicksilver on my old G5 Mac, although I used Firefox on that machine.)

Comment: Take a look at [this related thread](http://groups.google.com/group/blacktree-quicksilver/browse_thread/thread/cbe004a5696cf499?pli=1)

Answer (score 3):

There is now a [Google Chrome plugin for Quicksilver](https://github.com/ndreas/GoogleChrome-qsplugin) (with [documentation](https://github.com/ndreas/GoogleChrome-qsplugin/blob/master/Documentation.markdown)). Version 1.0 was released on April 27, 2012.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with a custom trigger:

- `Item`: a bookmark from Safari or Firefox
- `Action`: `Open URL With...`
- `Target`: Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no Chrome plugin for Quicksilver, so you can't access your Chrome bookmarks directly. But you can sync your Chrome bookmarks with Safari, using something like [xMarks](http://www.xmarks.com/).

Then, once you installed the Safari Module, you can access those bookmarks with Quicksilver.

And when you use the "Open URL" action on those bookmarks, they will open in your default browser, which is Chrome.

Comment: If Quicksilver doesn't have a plugin for Chrome, why did he say he could do it with his old Mac?

Comment: @daviesgeek - If you re-read the question, you'll see I was doing it with Firefox on the old Mac.

Comment: @NeilFein Sorry! I didn't notice that.

Comment: Well, it is kind of like comparing apples and avacados. The question really should be, "How can I do [thing]?" rather than "how can I do [thing I did before with a different setup]?"

Comment: Btw. adding your voice to [this request for a Chrome Plugin](https://github.com/quicksilver/Quicksilver/issues/459) might help speed up the creation of said plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You could also drag the URLs from your browser (FF, Chrome, Safari all support this behavior, on 10.6.8 anyway) to create new .webloc files, add them to a specific folder named 'bookmarks' for example, then add that folder to Quicksilver's catalog from the 'File & Folder Scanner' and invoke opening them that way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free Quicksilver-like extension for Chrome called [Ferro](http://www.getferro.com) that opens bookmarked URLs, history URLs, and currently open tabs. It also has many other commands besides open, including extension management, tab pinning, deleting bookmarks, etc. Also provides a keyboard interface to session management and tab extraction. [getferro.com](http://www.getferro.com)